# Python 3 multiporcessing or multi-threads for multiple functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization

I want to utilize all my computer's cores to run the following Pseudocode (the actual code is too long):

```
def function2(modifiedList):

    process modifiedList

    return value 

mainList = [a, b, c,...,z]

def function1(mainList):
    process mainList
    create modifiedList

    result = function2(modifiedList)

return result

calculator(function1)
```

Not sure how to do multiporcessing or multi-threads when a function is called from inside another function.

Comment: Can you fix your indents? I don't understand what `calculator(function1)` is supposed to do or what part you want parallelized. A good way to do pseudo code is an actual functioning python program that just runs on silly example data.

Comment: You almost certainly won't get any speed up from using threading because of the GIL. If you want to use more cores, you'll need multiprocessing

Answer (score 0):

You should look at https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html module in standard library.

However, the code you posted would not be easy to parallelize, because of it's sequential nature.

A much better approach would be to find an easily parallelizable part of your problem and work from there.

As the documentation says, if your list is long enough, and you can process each element independently, you could try to substitute

```
for i in l:
    result.append(f(i))
```

with

```
result = p.map(f, l)
```